# Make ul tags behave properly when having a float element wrapping it

Tags: html, css

```
#wrap{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

ul{
    list-style: square;
}

<div id="wrap">
    MEH!
</div>

<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>

<p>Perfect stuff!</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2p8Z/3/

As you can see, the bullet points appears inside the box.

The requirement is not changing the HTML or the #wrap CSS. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Either shift the bullets in:

```
ul {
    list-style: square inside;
}
```

Or shift the entire list in with some margin/padding:

```
ul {
    list-style: square;
    margin-left: 1em; /* Or padding-left: 1em */
}
```

There is a slight difference between these two: the margin/padding solution lets you adjust how far out you want to push the list items. Either solution works here, though.

The difference is more significant if your `li` text spans multiple lines; having an `inside` list position means only the line with the bullet point gets pushed in. Margin/padding on the `ul` or the `li` elements doesn't cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set margin-left:236px on the ul. 
Or the easy way would be to set:

```
ul{
 list-style-position:inside;
}
```

They both have the same effect.

EDIT:  If you want to make sure that both the ul and the text below it are aligned then you should wrap them in a div and add the margin to that div:

```
<div id="right-col">
  <ul>
    <li>bullet</li>
  </ul>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#right-col{
  margin-left:236px;
}
```

Comment: but this will make the second line of the text not aligned with the first line of text, rather, it aligns with the bullet point.